# Is there a way to print posts?

Tags: feature-request, export

After stumbling upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/2567683) great post, I've encountered a case where having a printable version would be of much value.

Is there a way to print posts from Stack Overflow ? If not are there plans to implement one?

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/

Comment: @Bart you should turn that into an answer - I've been around the site for a few years but I didn't know about that.

Comment: I don't understand... do you not know that browsers can, you know, print web pages? And you can print to virtual printers like PDF printers?

Comment: @Will are you familiar with WYSIWYG ? If browser printing was sufficient no site would have printing tools, but that's not the case now, is it ...

Comment: The CSS on SE has print media types, so the browser print on SO and other network sites seems to be sufficient..

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Oh, you need the pretty colors to be in all the right places.  Then use any website imaging tool to take your pretty picture and then print that.

Comment: @Will Oh the nihilism ... Thank god there are people in software that understand the difference between `need` and `want` or `I'd like` or `it'd be cool`. Carry on people, nothing to see here I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @Will Actually the CSS for printing is not good since only the left part of the page is filled, the right part being empty, which gives super long documents which are difficult to read and consume a lot of paper. So the question is absolutely relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of plans to implement such functionality, but you can already achieve the same in several ways.

Of course there is your humble <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or the suitable combination for your particular platform), which actually doesn't work all that bad (though I'm unaware if that's browser-specific and linked to my use of Chrome).

An alternative is [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/). It allows you to enter the question ID of one of the questions on the site (you can find this in the URL) and it will generate a printer friendly version.

Comment: Nearly made this an answer, because I think it's a great solution. Create a bookmark out of the Bookmarklet on [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), and then click that from any Question that you want to print, without having to remember the question number.

Comment: It feels fundamentally wrong that something so core to a technical Q&A site has to be done from outside the site altogether.  Can Stack Exchange just add the link to StackPrinter on each question?  Relying on plugins to add it is a discoverability problem.

Comment: @Berin We don't run StackPrinter, so that's a definitive no. Security teams would never approve of that.

Comment: @simo.3792 so who is running it ?? it's been down for a while now: 'Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.'

Answer (score 3):

#### No StackExchange formatting

Go with [stackprinter.com](https://stackprinter.com)

Repository owner [systempuntoout](https://github.com/systempuntoout) pointer out that it's possible to print answer only. Check out their [API](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/api.txt).

Example:
[www.stackprinter.com/export?question=362113&service=superuser&answer=362115](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=362113&service=superuser&answer=362115)

#### Formatted single answer

User [Don't Panic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2734189/dont-panic) almost gave us perfect [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356328/6857902) but you can make it better:

I will demonstrate it on this nice answer: `https://superuser.com/a/362115/1291940`

```
one_of_stack_site = superuser.com
answer_id = 362115
revision_number = 3
```

Start with 1 and increment till you find version of the answer you want to print.

1. `https://{one_of_stack_site}/revisions/{answer_id}/{revision_number}`
2. Open programming tools of your browser (DevTools for Chrome, Web Developer Tools <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for Firefox)
3. Go to Inspect
4. Remove all the blocks which are unneeded for printing. Browser should highlight what block you are on, thus you can just simply press delete on that. Be careful not to delete too much of the post.

https://superuser.com/revisions/362115/3

From this:

[image: Print version of the answer includes the site logo, the question title, edit information, and which number answer it is.]

To this:

[image: Print version of the answer that only contains the body of the answer.]