# Make an answer printable

Tags: feature-request, answers

I found such an awesome answer, that I want to print and put on my office door to make everyone read it before asking.

Yes, like in 1995, with a real printer. But I don't want to print the whole page. Just the answer.

When I get it right, [it should not be that big issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997123/print-specific-part-of-webpage) in terms of implementation.

Is someone with me on that fr?

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/

Comment: Well, on the odd ocasion I might want to do that, I would just use 'Print Screen' and the clipoard to copypasta the answer bitmap to some other thing like 'Paint' that can print.

Comment: @Cody how do I get the answer id? Edit: or just make stack printer print an answer only?

Comment: Look at the "share" link. It is of the form "https://stackoverflow.com/a/<postID>/<userID>".  The part in <postID> is what you're looking for.

Comment: Click the "share" link underneath the answer. The answer ID is the slug immediately after `/a/` in the URL. (Oh, but I don't think Stack Printer supports just answers. It only prints questions. Dunno if there's [a related tool](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) that does answers.)

Comment: Some browsers support printing part of a page. E.g. on Chrome, there's a "Selection only" option on the print dialog, so you can just select/highlight the answer, then print. (Or [this related question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/612592/how-can-i-save-only-selected-part-of-web-page-with-google-chrome))

Comment: *"Yes, like in 1995, with a real printer."* Brilliant.

Answer (score 6):

They already are printable.

Just go to `https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/{answer_id}/{revision_number}`

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> it.

(There's still a little revision-related content at the top, so it's not *perfect*, but that page will be just the answer, no question, comments, etc. - probably good enough for sticking on a door, at any rate.)

---

If the answer has been edited, you can navigate to this by first clicking on the "edited" link underneath it, then selecting the "link" link for the revision you want. If the answer hasn't been edited yet, you can get the answer id from the "share" link under it (it's the first number in that link), and the revision number will just be 1.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH5sG.png

Answer (score 2):

For the few occasions you'd want to do this, just take a screenshot or copy-paste it to a text editor and print that.

No need to spend development effort on such an unimportant feature, imho.

Comment: I want to do this on many occasions.